# Java Predicates In clause: illegal argument exception?

Tags: java, hibernate, predicate, hibernate-criteria, illegalargumentexception

I am trying to create a java `predicate` that gets all entities that match a certain Id:

```
 public Predicate createPredicate(List<Integer> personIds){
 
 Predicate newPredicate = null;
 if(!personIds.isEmpty()){
      CriteriaBuilder.In<Integer> inClause = builder.in(from.get(PERSON_ID));
      for (Integer personId : personIds) {
        inClause.value(personId);
      }
      newPredicate = builder.in(inClause);
    }

    return newPredicate;
  }
```

However when I try to get the count results from this (see below) I get an `illegal argument exception`.

What is the issue?

```
private Long getResultsCount(Predicate predicate) throws ATSException {

    CriteriaBuilder countBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Long> countQuery = countBuilder.createQuery(Long.class);
    Root<Person> countFrom = countQuery.from(Person.class);
    countQuery = countQuery.select(countBuilder.count(countFrom));
   
    countQuery.where(predicate);

    return entityManager.createQuery(countQuery).getSingleResult();
  }
```

Error:

```
   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: in near line 1, column 177 [select count(generatedAlias0) from com.model.Person as generatedAlias0 where ( generatedAlias0.status=:param0 ) and ( ( generatedAlias0.personId in () in () ) and ( ( generatedAlias0.personId in () in () ) and ( generatedAlias0.personId in () in () ) ) )]\r\n\tat org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1374)\r\n\tat
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generated query contains the following 3 times:

```
( generatedAlias0.personId in () in () )
```

My guess is that this is the reason:

```
newPredicate = builder.in(inClause);
```

`inClause` is already translated to "in (...)", so you're asking the criteria builder to include an `IN` inside an `IN`.

Does your code work if you remove that line?

And it's probably easier to use the `Expression.in` method. Since `from.get(PERSON_ID)` returns an `Expression`, this should work:

```
public Predicate createPredicate(List<Integer> personIds){
    return personIds.isEmpty()
            ? null
            : from.get(PERSON_ID).in(personIds);
}
```